# Angular async OnInit

Tags: angular, async-await

I am really new to angular, and wanted to understand how can i call async on Oninit. I have one service which is using asyn/await. i want to be able to use this in OnInit. however, I am not able to use it. because before service call is complete code executes to next line and it throws ZoneawarePromise error.

My Service method looks like below

```
 public async getProjects():Promise<Observable<any>>{
    const querySpec = {query: "SELECT * from c"};
    const { resources:items } = await this.container.items.query(querySpec).fetchAll();
    return of(items);
  }
```

and this is how i am trying to call it within ngOnInit

```
async ngOnInit(){
      (await this.projectData.getProjects()).subscribe(data=>{
   
       //All the other code goes here, basically creating a HTML content
```

what could be the right way to call a service ?

Comment: Why are you turning your promise into an observable? `return of(items);`. `getProjects` should just return an `Observable` or a promise not both

Answer (score 1, accepted):

your problem is `Promise of Observable`,

```
 public async getProjects():Promise<Array<any>>{
    const querySpec = {query: "SELECT * from c"};
    const { resources:items } = await this.container.items.query(querySpec).fetchAll();
    return items;
  }
```

then

```
async ngOnInit(){
      const data = await this.projectData.getProjects();
      console.log('data',data);
```

Comment: Thanks for the reply, Now, I am getting ERROR TypeError: Cannot read property 'toArray' of undefined.

Comment: I figured the issue. It was mainly because of not initialising the variables properly. once i did it. its working fine. Thanks